# Elixir Get Map containing maximum values of specific field

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

I'm a beginner in Elixir programming language.

I have an object something like this:

```
{
  id: uuid,
  created_at: DateTime.t,
  updated_at: DateTime.t,
  type: my_type
}
```

let's say `my_type` is one of `~w[A B C D]`

I want to write a function which takes a list of these objects and returns a following map:

```
%{
  A: 120,
  B: 220,
  C: 560,
  D: 0,
  any: 560
}
```

The values here has to be the MAXIMUM difference between `updated_at` and `created_at` columns(`Timex.diff(updated_at, created_at, :seconds)`) per `my_type` + `any` in addition.
In case of `any` the `my_type` is not considered and takes the maximum among all objects in the list.

What is the best way to do it in Elixir? Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you type out an exact example input and expected output here so answerers can try their solution out.

Comment: what exactly is not clear? I didn't type out exact example because need to provide date times and calculate differences. I thought I could avoid this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following will group the list by its type, then calculate the max difference for each group, and finally result in a map containing each type as the key and max difference as the value.

```
map = list
|> Enum.group_by(& &1.type)
|> Enum.map(fn {type, values} ->
  max =
    values
    |> Enum.map(fn %{created_at: created_at, updated_at: updated_at} ->
      # return the difference here
    end)
    |> Enum.max
  {type, max}
end)
|> Map.new
```

This should give you something like:

```
%{
  A: 120,
  B: 220,
  C: 560,
  D: 0
}
```

You can calculate the value for `any` now by doing `map |> Map.values |> Enum.max`.

Comment: [`Enum.max_by/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#max_by/3)? Also, instead of `group_by` there is a room to use the ability of `Keyword` to have multiple values for the same key and a comprehension like `for %{type: t, v1: v1, v2: v2} <- list, res <- {t, v1 - v2}, do: res, into: []`.

Comment: `Enum.max_by/3` returns the original element of the list, not the mapped value so that'll require calculating the difference again. I don't see how `into: []` is going to work here. We need the max value per type. Unless you mean running the group_by after this `for`, which should work.

Comment: I have posted the solution that uses comprehension and does not use [`Enum.group_by`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#group_by/3) as an answer for the sake of diversity.

Answer (score 2):

I am posting this here for the sake of formatting and diversity. The answer by @Dogbert is likely better fit, although this approach could be more straightforward and arguably flexible.

```rb
list = [%{type: :a, v1: 10, v2: 20},
        %{type: :a, v1: 10, v2: 30},
        %{type: :b, v1: 10, v2: 20},
        %{type: :c, v1: 10, v2: 20}]

kw = for %{type: t, v1: v1, v2: v2} <- list,
       do: {t, v2 - v1}, into: []
#⇒ [a: 10, a: 20, b: 10, c: 10]

kw
|> Enum.sort_by(fn {_, v} -> v end, &>=/2)
|> Enum.uniq_by(fn {k, _} -> k end)
#⇒ [a: 20, b: 10, c: 10]
```